# Helmholtz decomposition and the fundamental solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The Helmholtz decomposition of a vector field $\mathbf{F}$ is given
by $\mathbf{F} = -\nabla \Phi + \nabla \times \mathbf{A}$.
Wikipedia gives an [explicit formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) for $\Phi$ and $\mathbf{A}$.
They look to be obtained from convolving the divergence and curl of $\mathbf{F}$
by the fundamental solution of the Laplacian. Why is this?

Comment: Haven't you noticed that Wikipedia also gave a [reference](http://www.cems.uvm.edu/~keoughst/LectureNotes141/Topic_03_(Helmholtz'%20Theorem).pdf) for this theorem?